# Multiple Form Submission Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, user-experience

I have a form with validation, I need to prevent multiple form submission during lag time before redirect.  Any ideas on how to do this while maintaing a good user experience?

Comment: hiden token field and session variable

Comment: Hide the submit button on submit.

Comment: Hidden token looks like it might be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can try hiding the submit button on click

Comment: Preferably I want to handle it server side.